# flutter packages : everytime I try to run the app it is take to asset_bundle.dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

everytime I try to run the app it is take to **asset_bundle.dart**

```
 if (asset == null)
      throw FlutterError('Unable to load asset: $key');
    return asset;
```

is the code right ?

```
        @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 159, 163, 167),
          title: Text('SOUND EFFECTZ',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Raleway',
              )),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final player = AudioPlayer();
                  await player.setSource(AssetSource('bleep-41488.mp3'));
                },
                child: Text('mucia'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I try to use  flutter packages ( audioplayers) and in GitHub written that I should use
`await player.setSource(AssetSource('sounds/coin.wav'));`

but when I use it I have a error (The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.) what should I do??  This is the link to the place where I read the explanation and it asks me to do that https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md

and can anyone tell me how to learn more about flutter packages I find it very difficult to understand and I feel lost as a beginner. Thank you

edit : I add (async) to my code in the first error disappear but now I have this one

> Exception has occurred. MissingPluginException
> (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider))

Comment: can you extend your code a bit so we can see the context, especially of the first code block? From what I see so far player should be a variable you store in the class, not in the onPressed() function. On learning Flutter I can very much recommend Angela Yu's flutter bootcamp.

Comment: I'm still puzzled. How do the two code parts interact? The first one is from a different dart file, right? What is the `asset` variable it is checking? There is no such variable in the second code block

Comment: I didn't get you well, but the first code was the problem. aww, I really don't understand anything. Every time I write a code, I get hundreds of errors. The best thing is to look for something else to learn in flutter this application I cannot implement thank you anyway <3

Comment: learning Flutter is not super easy, I can really recommend angela yu's course. You create quite some apps yourself, in the end even a chat application: https://www.appbrewery.co/p/flutter-development-bootcamp-with-dart